# meaning of 'F-able'

Tags: meaning

I was watching a sitcom and here is this part of the script.

A: Okay so what's the problem?

B: It's...I can't explain it.

A: TRY!

B: It's.... ineffable.

A: I am not "F-able"?

B: No, no, no, no. Ineffable, ineffable means it can't be explained

For your information, 
A used to be B's girlfriend (B dumped her) and a few years later B wanted to meet her again and they have become a couple again. However, again, B doesn't want to go out with her for some reason and tries to say her that they aren't meant to be or something.

Comment: My guess not having seen it. It seems to be a joke. Plug in a certain F-word that should be obvious in context.

Answer (score 1):

“F-words” can be euphemisms for the word “fuck” and its derivatives. In your example, it expands to “fuckable”, which, given the circumstances, *A* (wrongly) believes is what *B* used to describe *A*, which then implements a comedic device.

Answer (score 0):

*F-ing* can be used as a milder, toned-down version of a more obscene word

> *fucking*

<sup>(Mouse over to see word)</sup>

For example, someone might say in an exasperated voice:

> *Just give me the F-ing hammer, will you?*

This would be pronounced as "effing" – and therefore a town like **Effingham** could easily become a set-up for a lot of jokes, as was done in [a suggestive radio skit](https://soundcloud.com/bobandtom/the-effing-house-family):

> **The Effing House Family Restaurant** (in Effingham, Illinois)
>
> *For lunch, try the huge Effing burger! And what about dinner? Juicy effing steaks...*

---

The sitcom writers have essentially employed the same humorous device, where *effible* is being confused with its homophone *F-able*.